# SQL Server execute stored procedure in update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

every updated record must have different value by using a procedure
the procedure returns single integer value

```
declare @value int;
exec @value = get_proc param;
update table1 set field1 = @value;
```

this will work for one record but i want the procedure to get new value for each record

Comment: Hard to say without more information. How exactly does the stored procedure determine what value would be appropriate for each row? Depending on what the stored procedure does it may be possible to create a table-valued function instead, and join to that.

Comment: it's returning serial number via some algorithm for special purpose
when update each record must have new serial number

Comment: Well if you can perform that logic in a table-valued function, that would be the way to go. What is the column in table1 that determines what @value will be?

Comment: I guess i will use a function as you suggested thanks

Comment: I've added an example. Of course I can't get any more specific as I have no idea what the procedure does, but hopefully it gets you started.

Comment: Can you show your stored procedure? If you can perform your logic on many rows at once, it will be far superior performance to doing the logic over and over again, one row at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a quick example of how to use a TVF to perform this type of update:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1(ID INT, Column1 INT);

INSERT dbo.Table1(ID)
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CalculateNewValue
(@ID INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    -- no idea what this logic would be,
    -- just showing an example

    RETURN(SELECT NewValue = @ID + 1);
GO

SELECT t1.ID, n.NewValue
    FROM dbo.Table1 AS t1 
    CROSS APPLY dbo.CalculateNewValue(t1.ID) AS n;
```

Results:

```
ID NewValue
-- --------
 1        2
 2        3
 3        4
```

Now an update that uses the same information:

```
UPDATE t1 SET Column1 = n.NewValue
    FROM dbo.Table1 AS t1 
    CROSS APPLY dbo.CalculateNewValue(t1.ID) AS n;

SELECT ID, Column1 FROM dbo.Table1;
```

Results:

```
ID Column1
-- -------
 1       2
 2       3
 3       4
```

Comment: this great stuff you made it almost like what i have done till now 
thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Does it really need to be a procedure ? If you can implement get_proc as function, then you can apply it on every record that you want ;)

Also, what are you using value1 for ? In the example that you've provided, it's not needed.